# SQL Query to bring group result of a column in multiple Column

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to make a query which generate this kind of result

```
EmpId,  EmpSickLeave,EmpCasualLeave, EmpAnnualLeave, TotalLeave
1,       1,           0,                0            1
2,       0,           0,                2            2
3,       0,           1,                0            1
4,       0,           1,                0            1  
5,       1,           0,                0            1
```

while I have two tables

**Table EmpLeave:: include a column EmpId, Date, EmpLeaveTypeID**

**Table EmpLeaveType:: include EmpLeaveTypeID and LeaveName**

DATA In tables

```
EmpLeaveType Table
EmpLeaveTypeID , LeaveName
1,              Sick Leave
2,              Annual
3,              Casual

EmpLeave Table
column EmpId, Date, EmpLeaveTypeID
            1, 2015-07-01, 1
            3, 2015-07-02, 2
            5, 2015-07-04, 1
            4, 2015-07-04, 2
            2, 2015-07-05, 2
            2, 2015-07-07, 2
```

I am pulling my hair and unable to brind this kind of result. Is this possible?

```
  EEmpId,  EmpSickLeave,EmpCasualLeave, EmpAnnualLeave, TotalLeave
1,       1,           0,                0            1
2,       0,           0,                2            2
3,       0,           1,                0            1
4,       0,           1,                0            1  
5,       1,           0,                0            1
```

This wrong thing I have tried!

```
    SELECT * count(EmpLeaveTypeID) FROM `EmpLeaveType`
WHERE SwitchDate Between '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-28'
group by EmpLeaveType, EmpId
```

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, but for reference your data does not correspond with your proposed results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below :

```
 SELECT 
 temp.EmpId , 
 temp.EmpSickLeave, 
 temp.EmpCasualLeave, 
 temp.EmpAnnualLeave,
 (temp.EmpSickLeave + temp.EmpCasualLeave + temp.EmpAnnualLeave ) 
 as  TotalLeave 
 FROM 
( SELECT 
 EmpId, 
 SUM( CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as EmpSickLeave,
 SUM( CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as EmpCasualLeave,
 SUM( CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) as EmpAnnualLeave
 FROM EmpLeave 
 WHERE Date Between '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-28'
 group by EmpId ) temp
```

Comment: Unknown column 'EmpSickLeave ' in 'field list'

Answer (score 1):

Please try the SELECT query below. It does not take into consideration that leave types may be changed someday.
SQL fiddle link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fd13/2
The query simply does an conditional aggregate to calculate leaves for each employee.

```
SELECT 
EmpId, 
SUM(CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EmpSickLeave,
SUM(CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EmpCasualLeave,
SUM(CASE WHEN EmpLeaveTypeID=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as EmpAnnualLeave,
COUNT(1) as TotalLeave
FROM `EmpLeave`
WHERE Date Between '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-28'
group by EmpId
```

Comment: COUNT(1) as TotalLeave not showing correct information instead it showing same number for all recrods –

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan Please the SQL fiddle I posted in the answer. Definitely showing 2 with the sample set I posted.

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a conditional count, where you want to count only certain rows. To achieve this, you can use a `SUM` with a `CASE` statement:

```
select EmpId as EEmpId,
    sum(case when EmpLeaveTypeID = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as EmpSickLeave,
    sum(case when EmpLeaveTypeID = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as EmpCasualLeave,
    sum(case when EmpLeaveTypeID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as EmpAnnualLeave,
    count(*) as TotalLeave
from EmpLeave
where ...
group by EmpId
```

What this does is add either `0` or `1` for each row, based on whether the `EmpLeaveTypeID` matches. You can then use `COUNT` to get the total number of rows for the `TotalLeave` column, as I have shown above.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7260a/1)

Comment: count(*) as TotalLeave not showing correct information instead it showing same number for all recrods

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing, but check the SQL Fiddle demo; it works

Comment: yeah i checked you right. I don't know it is not working form me:( although remaining result is fine:)

Answer (score 0):

I have omitted the `date between`, as it's a simple `where` addition.

Try the SQL query below:

```
select a.EmpId, count(Date), LeaveName from EmpLeave as a, mpLeaveType as b
where a.EmpLeaveTypeID = b.id
group by a.EmpId, a.EmpLeaveTypeID
```

Check the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37dc6/1)